# Airflow - Stop backfill

Tags: python, python-3.x, airflow

I'm using Airflow 1.10.12 and I have a DAG that run daily with the following parameters :

```
default_args = {
    'start_date': days_ago(365),
    'end_date': days_ago(1),
    'depends_on_past': False,
}
```

When I run the dag, there will be 365 DAG runs.

It seems I can only see the active DAG runs.
When I delete the current DAG runs, the following DAG runs are then triggered until I reach 365 DAG runs...

Is there a way I can stop the backfill ?
(I mean delete all the DAG runs)

Have a nice day

Comment: Do you want to delete the 365 DAG runs that ran on launch? or not run the 365 DAG at all when you turn it on?

Comment: On lunch. I faced the issue when I launched the backfill and then wonder that there was a mistake in the code that was running.

Comment: hmm, I am not quite following but `catchup=False` will not automatically backfill on launch. You can backfill by cli still after the launch if you need.  Or if you want to run 365 days on launch but want to delete all after the run, then you should not set `catchup`. Then there is a way to delete already ran DAGs but I would like to clarify what you are looking for first. https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/dag-run.html#catchup

Comment: The point is not to set catchup to 0 or 1. If I backfill by cli, is there a way to stop it ?